# MinioClient doesn't return userMetaData

Tags: java, amazon-s3, minio-client

My goal is to list all the objects in a bucket that contain some keys and values.
So in short I need an API where I assign a `Map<String,String>` to an object upload it to S3 and can find it later using this Map.

For this I use MinioClient https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/developers/java/API.html

I thought that I could upload an object and add userMetadata to it:

```
    var builder = PutObjectArgs.builder()
            .bucket(bucket)
            .object(objectName)
            .userMetadata(userMetadata)
            .stream(inputStream, -1, DEFAULT_PART_SIZE);

    minioClient.putObject(builder.build());
```

and then list all the objects with the specified prefix using the flag `.includeUserMetadata(true)`:

```
   Iterable<io.minio.Result<io.minio.messages.Item>> minioClient.listObjects(ListObjectsArgs.builder()
                                        .bucket(bucket)
                                        .recursive(true)
                                        .prefix(pathPrefix)
                                        .includeUserMetadata(true)
                                        .build())
```

and then check whether `item.userMetadata` contains all the entries from the map used as a filter.

However all the items have `userMetadata = null`. Why?

Currently I workaround the problem by calling `minioClient.statObject()` on each item:
var statObjectMetadata =

```
var userMetadata = minioClient.statObject(StatObjectArgs.builder()
                                            .bucket(bucket)
                                            .object(item.objectName())
                                            .build()).userMetadata();
```

It would be great if someone knows another solution to this problem.

Using

```
<minio.version>8.5.2</minio.version>
```

P.S.
I updated the version to 8.5.3 and `includeUserMetadata(true)` began working, but I noticed that it doesn't contain the same key in userMetadata I used before uploading the object to the storage. For example I used the key `my_file_type` but item contained `X-Amz-Meta-My_file_type`.